# Adding large amount of records into a query

Tags: sql, excel, import

Completely new to sql, I got an excel file with data and I'm looking for a way to manually import this into a query without having to copy record by record. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: sql server has an import wizard that will import an excel worksheet into a table.

Comment: I see, I thought there could be a way to do this manually

Comment: have a look at this link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/